# error: 'fxVolumeSlider' undeclared (first use in this function) - Need to declare IBOUTLET?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

Okay well now im trying to get the volume to change on the slider

here is the code

```
@implementation MainerViewController
@synthesize fxVolumeSlider;

- (IBAction)pushPlay:(id)sender; {
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"wav"];
    if (theAudio) [theAudio release];
    theAudio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];
    theAudio.delegate = self;
    [theAudio play];    
    volumeTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.05 target:self selector:@selector(updateVolume) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

}

-(void)updateVolume {
    [theAudio setVolume:fxVolumeSlider.value];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Setup custom slider images
    UIImage *minImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"grey_track.png"];
    UIImage *maxImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"white_track.png"];
    UIImage *tumbImage= [UIImage imageNamed:@"metal_screw.png"];

    minImage=[minImage stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:10.0 topCapHeight:0.0];
    maxImage=[maxImage stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:10.0 topCapHeight:0.0];

    // Setup the FX slider
    [fxVolumeSlider setMinimumTrackImage:minImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [fxVolumeSlider setMaximumTrackImage:maxImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [fxVolumeSlider setThumbImage:tumbImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    fxVolumeSlider.minimumValue = 0.0;
    fxVolumeSlider.maximumValue = 1.0;
    fxVolumeSlider.continuous = YES;
    //fxVolumeSlider.value = [sharedSoundManager fxVolume];

    // Attach an action to sliding
    [fxVolumeSlider addTarget:self action:@selector(fxSliderAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

    // Cleanup
    minImage = nil;
    maxImage = nil;
    tumbImage = nil;
}
- (void) fxSliderAction:(id)sender {
    [theAudio setFxVolume:fxVolumeSlider.value];
}
```

However i now get this error

warning: 'AVAudioPlayer' may not respond to '-setFxVolume:'

So everytime i play the play button, i try to adjust the volume but i get kicked out of the app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've declared both the ivar and the property as `_fxVolumeSlider` but what you use within the method is `fxVolumedSlider`. Both are not the same. You should use `_fxVolumeSlider` or what you probably meant was to declare the property as

```
@property(retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISlider *fxVolumeSlider;
```

and synthesize it using

```
@synthesize fxVolumeSlider = _fxVolumeSlider;
```

But even then you can't use it as `fxVolumeSlider`. You can use it as `self.fxVolumeSlider` or `_fxVolumeSlider`. If you want to use it as plain `fxVolumeSlider`, you should replace all `_fxVolumeSlider`s with `fxVolumeSlider`.

Comment: I think the method you're looking for is `setVolume:` and not `setFxVolume:`.

Answer (score 1):

Check the underscore in the declaration. In the .h file, you have:

```
IBOutlet UISlider *_fxVolumeSlider;
```

You should have:

```
IBOutlet UISlider *fxVolumeSlider;
```

Also, in the .m file, edit the line

```
@synthesize _fxVolumeSlider;
```

to be

```
@synthesize fxVolumeSlider;
```

As to your revised issue:

```
- (void) fxSliderAction:(id)sender {
    [theAudio setFxVolume:fxVolumeSlider.value];
}
```

should instead read as

```
- (void) fxSliderAction:(id)sender {
    [theAudio setVolume:fxVolumeSlider.value];
}
```

Watch out for typos (and look for them before posting!)

Comment: Okay thanks now it works, but the uislider isnt changing, ive linked it up in interface builder

Comment: Reset the links now that you've changed the declared name (this is what the IB recognizes).

Comment: Another typo perhaps. Where did you declare and synthesize `fxVolume`?

Comment: At the top of the .m
`@implementation MainerViewController
@synthesize fxVolumeSlider;
`

Comment: **TYPO**: `fxVolume` is not the same as `fxVolumeSlider`

Comment: Last time... read the above. You are not trying to set the slider are you? No. You are trying to set `volume`. Look at the last bit of my answer. Set what you mean to set.